# Reading Math Functions in Assembly

Tags: c, math, assembly, x86, instructions

I'm translating a bit of x86 Assembly to C code. A small section of the assembly is giving me trouble.

```
mov %eax, %edx
sar $0x1f, %edx
idivl -0x18(%ebp)
mov %edx, %eax
```

Our eax value starts off with 0 in it. Then we shift and rotate by 0x1f (31). I know that shift right is divide by 2...what happens if you shift and rotate to a number? Is it also /2? Then we divide by the element at space -0x18(%ebp) which we'll call int x. Or does idivl work in a different way? Then we put it back into %eax and I get the rest of the program easily.

Some help would be appreciated. The main thing I don't understand is the sar instruction

Comment: I'm not an expert in x86 assembly, but isn't `sar` an arithmetic right shift?

Comment: It is. How would that effect the number?  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate

Comment: If you're using the Intel syntax, from what I can find, it looks like `sar $0x1f, %edx` is equivalent to dividing `$0x1f` by 2, `%edx` times, and rounding towards negative infinity. If you're using GAs syntax, it's the same operation with the numbers flipped: divigind `%edx` by 2 `$0x1f` times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet of assembly just performs a signed 32-bit modulo operation:

```
a %= x;
```

The `sar` instruction is an arithmetic right shift (a right shift which preserves the sign of the operand); looking at the first two instructions:

```
mov %eax, %edx
sar $0x1f, %edx
```

This sign-extends the contents of `%eax` into the double register `%edx:%eax`; in pseudo-C code:

```
edx_eax = (int64_t)eax;
```

The next two instructions:

```
idivl -0x18(%ebp)
mov %edx, %eax
```

perform a signed 64-bit divide, with the resulting remainder in `%edx`, which is then transferred to `%eax`. In pseudo-C code again:

```
edx = (int32_t)(edx_eax % x);
eax = edx;
```

Comment: The answer was %= x; Thank you so much!